Cannot publish closed test app on play store
When I try to upload the app bundle I get a "Bundle unsigned" error despite having signed and uploaded the key

I ran the command "Generate digned bundle" in android studio

Then I click on "create new" under key store path

In the google play console I click on the "new release" under the internal tests field

I click on modify signing key

"Export and load from a java keystore"

I follow the instructions and upload the resultinig output.zip file

I upload the generated aab file

The file has a "Files in bundle must be signed" error



If you're letting Google manage the signing of the app, you only need an upload key and then you need to sign the bundle using the same upload key and upload the bundle
Go to Android studio's 'Build' - 'Generate Signed Bundle / Apk' - Choose ' Android App Bundle' - If you already have a key choose it or create new and sign the bundle then upload it
Upload and release keys are different. Once you choose google play signing you always sign your bundle with upload key and you don't have to worry about release key anymore. Play will check the signature of the uploaded bundle to make sure it's signed using the same upload key and if it is, they will use release key they've with them

How do I upload the upload keys then?

I tried like you suggested but I still get that same error. how do I upload those upload keys?
